# Obtain frame rate from MP4 with Media Foundation .NET

Tags: .net, video, frame, ms-media-foundation

I want to obtain the frames per second of a MP4 video file. Since MP4 is not supported by DirectShow, I am looking into other alternatives such as Media Foundation. The problem is that after hours of google, I wasn´t able to find an example where to learn how to use MediaFoundation. All I have found is in C++, I use VB or C#, and never understood how to do this simple task.

Comment: You should be able to get this via Windows 7+ `IPropertyStore` and [`PKEY_Video_FrameRate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). DirectShow solution is easy but involves a third party component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 (and possibly Windows Vista as well) provides you with shell API to access media file properties. This includes frame rate of video stream in MPEG-4 files (`.MP4`), so to get the frame rate you can access [`PKEY_Video_FrameRate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property in the property store via `IPropertyStore` interface.